# Avoid gulp.dest and override files?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm working on a large FS which I can't change:

```
/Javascript
/Javascript/FR
/Javascript/FR/FRA
/Javascript/FR/FRA/script1
/Javascript/FR/FRA/script1/Content
/Javascript/FR/FRA/script1/Content/script1.js
/Javascript/FR/FRA/script2
/Javascript/FR/FRA/script2/Content
/Javascript/FR/FRA/script2/Content/script2.js
[...]
/Styles
/Styles/FR
/Styles/FR/FRA
/Styles/FR/FRA/style1
/Styles/FR/FRA/style1/Content
/Styles/FR/FRA/style1/Content/style1.scss
/Styles/FR/FRA/style1/Content/img/svg1.svg
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content/style2.scss
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content/img/svg2.svg
[...]
```

There are more than 100 directories which I CAN'T and DON'T want to concatenate.

My Gulpfile.js sits in the root (/) and tasks are run from there.

I'd like to avoid the destination-path pipe I use into `gulp-imagemin`, `gulp-svgmin` or `gulp-ruby-sass` tasks:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
```

[...] and directly override my files with some suffix added before:

```
.pipe(rename({suffix: "-min"}))
```

I don't see a workaround with path/cwd or glob-stream.

Is there a way to keep gulping into the current working directory instead of a destination and get some overriding like:

```
[...]
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content/style2.scss
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content/style2.css
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content/img/svg2.svg
/Styles/FR/FRA/style2/Content/img/svg2-min.svg
```

Thanks for your help, here's my gulpfile.js: https://gist.github.com/aurelienlewin/9251972

Comment: What is the issue?  Have you tried just using the same src as the dest?

Comment: Sure, but as I want Gulp to work recursively, I tried :
`.pipe(gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA/**/*'))`

It crashed.

Or:
`.pipe(gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA/'))`

But it only output the .css file in the root directory.

Comment: I also tried :
`gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA/') // outputs CSS directly in the FRA/ root`,
`gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA') // outputs CSS directly in the FRA/ root`,
`gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA/**/*') // crashes`,
`gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA/**') // crashes`,
`gulp.dest('Styles/FR/FRA/*') // crashes`,
`gulp.dest('.') // outputs CSS in the / root`,
`gulp.dest('./') // outputs CSS in the / root`,

Comment: The relative root is based on the first glob pattern in the input.  If you are using the *exact* example from your link above, then setting the destination to `Styles/FR/FRA` should maintain the relative paths, such as `style2/Content/style2.css`.  There might be a bug in the SASS plugin stripping the relative part of the path.

Comment: Thanks @OverZealous, it must be linked to some SASS bug as you said. I'll try to reach their GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Must be some gulp-ruby-sass issue: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/27